# Can one filter out rows based on column type using R?

Tags: r

Does anyone know if it is possible to filter a tibble or data frame in R by variable type?  Basically `df <- df %>% filter(is.numeric(x))` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to grab all the columns of a certain type? If so, maybe you're looking for `select_if`?

Comment: thanks.  I'll try that.  Just looking for ideas.

Comment: Well, the way you phrased this is a little confusing, because `filter` is for acting on rows, and `select` is for acting on columns. Each column in a data frame (generally) will only ever be a single type, so "filtering rows by type" sounds a little weird.

Comment: Not weird....wrong.  I definitely phrased that wrong.  My apologies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548245/how-to-remove-columns-from-a-data-frame-by-data-type